# Ubuntu 14.04 frequent mouse freeze

Tags: 14.04, graphics, mouse, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 on my Asus (i5 core and 8GB Ram).

I experience frequent freezes of my screen. I cannot move the mouse, but I can use the keyboard. When it happens I could always open a command line with Ctrl+Alt+F2 and do `sudo service lightdm restart` to restart graphics.

But that of course does not fix the problem and is rather annoying since it happens rather often.

How I can find and fix the underlying issue here?

Greets and thanks in advance

Comment: Why did this question got downvoted? It's a legitimate question. I'm experiencing similar problem.

Comment: hint: no need to restart `lightdm`. simple switch to other tty, and then switch back to `C-A-F7`.

Comment: Check if your xorg get the mouse events correctly, login open a Terminal and enter: <code>$ xev</code> If your mouse freezes and <code>xev</code> doesn't show anything, when you use the mouse, then you have a driver issue.

Answer (score 10):

I get it occasionally in 12.04 LTS.  control+ALT+t will usually open a terminal window. `modprobe -r psmouse` followed by `modprobe psmouse` will usually fix it.

Check RAM by booting into GRUB.  Boot holding shift down, then test memory.

Comment: This seems to have worked in ubuntu 17.10.  Having to do this every time when my machine first boots will be annoying

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall the mouse driver :

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did that, but the problem keeps appearing.

Comment: +1 This appears to have fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I guess this does not work for people who are not currently connected to the Internet?

Comment: i got `unmet dependencies`, of `xorg-input-abi-20` and `xserver-xorg-core(>= 2:1.14.99.902)`. Synaptic showed that `xserver-xorg-input-mouse is broken`. I looked at `libevdev2`, and it also had some broken dependencies and synaptic solved somethings for me, I am not sure what happened. My mouse is working at the moment, will update once I am sure

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a process who reach 100% cpu usage a short amount of time?
Install htop & look if a process is reatching 100% cpu usage.

This is something I encounter with multiple instances of vlc or some others applications.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a screen freeze problem similar to the one you described, after a recent upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. The upgrade also led to occasional forced logout. My computer is running on an Intel i5 CPU and 4GB RAM.

I used *htop* to investigate what processes were keeping my CPU busy. I saw a suspicious process **compiz** and wondered what that was - this turned out to be a program used by the Unity window manager to enhance window graphics. So maybe those fancy graphic effects were slowing down my computer, I thought. Without further investigation, I tried my luck by switching to the *LXDE* window manager that is reputed to be light weighted.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Log out, then log in again selecting *lubuntu*.

I am so far very happy with the switch. User interaction has sped up. And I think the GUI is intuitive to a Windows user.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    dconf -reset -f /org/compiz
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-plugin.mouse KEY="s.mouse" VALUE="false"
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity
```

and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
xev
```

shows I have no input from mouse buttons or scroll wheels when this occurs.

```
sudo apt-get install  xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

shows unmet dependencies in xorg-input-abi-20  and xserver-xorg-core.

This was all working 5 minutes ago, and this is a relatively fresh (1 month) install of Ubuntu 14.04 on a new brainbox.

Not sure what to do next.  Mouse works for several days, then freezes, cursor moves but not able to pick or scroll.

Conky says CPU usage is 1%.  Should be good to go.  top says the usual suspects are running - chrome, thunderbird, nobody's hogging any CPU.

So far I've been hammering it with Alt-F2 sudo service restert lightdm, that's crude but at least I can move on.

/EDIT  tried sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get -f install, sudo apt-get autoremove.  Still have unmet dependencies.  Today the mouse is working fine, this is a very intermittent problem.

Answer (score -3):

Go to nvidia settings, profiles, and switch to Intel Power Saving. Logout and back in.

Comment: Consider adding a bit more about what you think might be the problem and solution.