# Ubuntu 14.04 not starting

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I was trying to solve my problem of freezing of the mouse every 1-2 minutes (I was able to use the keyboard though when the mouse stopped working. The mouse started working again when I removed it and inserted it into the USB port again). I used the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489907/ubuntu-14-04-frequent-mouse-freeze):

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-mouse`

This command told me that I am missing some essentials, so I tried installing them first.

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-core`

This removed and reinstalled a lot of components.

There was one more similar command that I entered which I am unable to recall. However, it returned an error and didn't install/remove anything.

Even after these, my mouse-related problem remained as it is.

After this I tried `Ctrl+Alt+F2` which opened a terminal but I didn't know how to troubleshoot from there, neither did I know how to come back from the terminal. So I simply shut down my PC.

Since then, Ubuntu is not starting. It's only showing the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo.

What damage have I done by blindly following the instructions?

How should I correct it?

System specs: 4GB RAM, Intel i3 processor.